# How to set self.parseClassName to a User Class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, parse-platform

I have to set a Parse Class Name for my PFQueryTableViewController, but I need to query all the users in my class. How would I be able to set self.parseClassName to a User Class? I tried:`self.parseClassName = @"_User";`, but that didn't work. Any ideas? I am using Xcode for this development. This is the error I get for using that class name.

```
2015-04-08 18:53:12.643 GPS Racing[76288:2673387] [Error]: bad characters in classname: (null) (Code: 103, Version: 1.6.4)
```

`2015-04-08 18:53:14.948 GPS Racing[76288:2673404] [Error]: bad characters in classname: (null) (Code: 103, Version: 1.6.4)
2015-04-08 18:53:17.678 GPS Racing[76288:2673388] [Error]: bad characters in classname: (null) (Code: 103, Version: 1.6.4)`

This is my full code. I am using storyboards, but I took this code from another app of mine that doesn't use storyboards.

```
    #import "FriendsViewController.h"

@interface FriendsViewController ()

@end

@implementation FriendsViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // Customize the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"TestClass";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"Ronen";

        // Uncomment the following line to specify the key of a PFFile on the PFObject to display in the imageView of the default cell style
        // self.imageKey = @"image";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 25;
    }
    return self;
}

// Override to customize what kind of query to perform on the class. The default is to query for
// all objects ordered by createdAt descending.
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
        return nil;
    }
    // you can always query the user class like this

    [query orderByAscending:@"username"];

    return query;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog (@"User ID:%@", [[PFUser currentUser] objectId]);

    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] block:^(PFObject *friends, NSError *error) {
        // Do something with the returned PFObject in the gameScore variable.

        NSArray *friendslist = [friends objectForKey:@"Friends"];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - Parse

- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    // This method is called every time objects are loaded from Parse via the PFQuery
}

- (void)objectsWillLoad {
    [super objectsWillLoad];

    // This method is called before a PFQuery is fired to get more objects
}

// Override to customize the look of a cell representing an object. The default is to display
// a UITableViewCellStyleDefault style cell with the label being the first key in the object.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"quoteText"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Code: %@", [object objectForKey:@"by"]];
    UITableViewCell *showDetail = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NextPage";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Load more...";

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    cell.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.objects.count;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The real problem was that I was using code for a class without storyboards. Here is the correct code:

```
-  (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithClassName:@"_User"];
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"_User";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell `style`
    self.textKey = @"FN";

    // Uncomment the following line to specify the key of a PFFile on the PFObject to display in the imageView of the default cell style
    // self.imageKey = @"image";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 25;
  }
 return self;
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [query orderByAscending:@"FN"];


    return query;

}
```

Don't forget to also set these parameters in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To create a query for user objects in objective-c, try using
 `PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];`, then setting the query parameters (i.e. 
`[query whereKey:@"playerName" notEqualTo:@"Michael Yabuti"];` 
)

More information found here: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS

Comment: That doesn't work, see this link for more info: https://parse.com/questions/why-does-querying-for-a-user-create-a-second-user-class And for some reason, I get this error even if I come up with a different class name?

Comment: How are you using parseClassName? I'm assuming it's a NSString*?  Where do you set the class name you are querying for?  if you're querying for user, you could use [PFUser query], which returns a query object for users. You still have to do the [query whereKey: equals: ] method, but that's the easiest way to set up a user query in obj - c.  I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: parseClassName is an NSString. I am using a PFQueryTableViewController to display the users and I need to input the parseClassName. I declare the parseClassName in my tableview.m

Answer (score 0):

My experience is it works perfectly like this  `self.parseClassName = @"User";`. If this version doesn't work please add more code, because it would be easier to help with more  information.

In this case you don't use the `self.parseClassName` ivar in the `queryForTable` which returns the query for the `PFQueryTableViewController`.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"User";
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;
        self.objectsPerPage = 10;

    }
    return self;
}
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
        return nil;
    }
    // you can always query the user class like this
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];

    [query orderByAscending:@"username"];

    // or query another an class like this
    PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"yourCustomClass"];

    return query;


}
```

Comment: Whenever I use this, the TableView shows 2 cells (I'm assuming because I have 2 users), that both say Code: (null)